# Not getting the current iPhone language

Tags: ios, swift

Initially, my iPhone language was English. Later, I changed it to French. And when I printed `Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations.first`, it was correctly printing the current language as `fr`.

Now I changed it back to English. But still when I print `Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations.first` the language is still being shown as `fr` i.e. French instead of English. Also, I changed the language to Hindi. But still, `Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations.first` prints `fr`.

What could be the reason for this...?

Comment: Try restarting your device?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following:

1. If you're on a Mac, press CMD + K, which will clean the build folder. Now try running your program and see what's being printed.
2. Try to select a different emulation device and see if the problem persists.